# SQL SELECT query over 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a basic understanding of sql and have built a small database that has to be submitted in 24 hours. I have made a schema in sqlfiddle here
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28fcd

I need to run a query that will search for a staff member (from table occurrence or teaching) and return the module_code and module_title (from table course) for the courses taught by said staff member.
I have spent a day and a half trying to solve this (which probably makes me quite dim) and am now desperate for some help.

The table schema is below. Apologies if this is not the way things are done.

```
CREATE TABLE course (
module_code VARCHAR (10),
module_title VARCHAR (40),
PRIMARY KEY (module_code));

CREATE TABLE teaching (
staff VARCHAR (40),
room VARCHAR (10),
PRIMARY KEY (staff));

CREATE TABLE occurrence (
module_code VARCHAR (10),
Instance VARCHAR (1),
staff VARCHAR (40),
year INT (1),
hours INT (2),
PRIMARY KEY (instance, module_code),
FOREIGN KEY (staff) REFERENCES teaching (staff));

INSERT INTO teaching VALUES
('Louise Ashby','C2-07a'),
('Abdul Razak','C2-09'),
('Brennen Tighe','C2-06'),
('Andrew Parker','C2-04'),
('Tim Goddard','C2-04');

INSERT INTO course VALUES
('CPU4000','Core Skills'),
('CPU4003','Introduction to Programming'),
('CPU4005','Networking Fundamentals');

INSERT INTO occurrence VALUES
('CPU4000','A','Louise Ashby',1,5),
('CPU4000','B',NULL,1,0),
('CPU4000','C',NULL,1,0),
('CPU4003','A','Abdul Razak',1,6),
('CPU4003','B','Brennen Tighe',1,6),
('CPU4003','C','Andrew Parker',1,6),
('CPU4005','A','Tim Goddard',1,0),
('CPU4005','B',NULL,1,0),
('CPU4005','C',NULL,1,0);
```

The SQL i am using is a little like:
SELECT module_title, module_code
FROM course, occurrence
WHERE occurrence.staff = 'Louise Ashby';

This tells me that Column 'module_code' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: What does your SQL look like? What results is it producing? What results is it supposed to produce instead?

Comment: I was careful to be precise in what i was asking, and i have been exactly not clear. Inner stupidity taking over! What i actually need to do is search for the course taught by a particular tutor. Say if i take the name Louise Ashby, i would want to return the module_title and module_code for the courses she teaches. Sorry for the ambiguity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query is like:

```
select c.* from course c
inner join occurrence o on o.module_code = c.module_code 
where o.staff = 'Louise Ashby'
```

Based on your schema. However, in a real world application, you wouldn't use such a schema.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand that at all. Is c. supposed to mean course and o occurrence, and * is a wildcard. i dont wish to return a wildcard, or i dont think i do.

Comment: well that works, but i am no less confused. If i could possibly trouble you a little further, could you possibly talk me through it, as i need to understand and learn from it.

Comment: course c, occurence o - makes c and o local aliases for course and occurence respectively. In Sql select * means select all fields, and select c.* here means select all fields from c (courses).

Comment: Thank you. I think i understand that. It would appear that whenever i take a small step forward that a wall of stupidity awaits me. Thanks. Scott

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  `teaching`.staff,
  `course`.module_code,
  `course`.module_title
from
  `teaching`
inner join
  `occurrence` on
  `occurrence`.staff = `teaching`.staff
inner join
  `course` on
  `course`.module_code = `occurrence`.module_code
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your tables aliases when joining them together. The * means 'all'. So the above query is selecting all columns from c table where your condition is met. The ambiguous error was probably because you wernt specifying what keys to join the table on. Hope that helps.

Sorry, meant to reply to your comment not add an answer. Still new to stackoverflow.